# NextJs or pure ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

While I understand the benefits of NextJs like SSR (hence SEO support), builtin routing and image rendering optimisation, we still need to use some sort of state management library like Redux, Thunk etc for the app wide state management. While the React team suggests to use NextJs, I am a bit concern about what are the key benefits other than what I mentioned above. Even for the routing part as per React.dev, it was still in beta till March 2023 and it doesn't provide any support for Rail guard to protect secured sites.

I am about to kickoff a new project and confused if I embark on NextJs or use something like Vite and stick to pure react including the React Router.

Comment: You should learn more about what Next.js is. There isn't a choice between Next.js and React. React is just a Javascript framework, even more simply it's just a Javascript file. You still need some server to actually serve content, handle routes, authentication, etc. You could build your own server, or use Next.js, or any other server solution, or make a purely static site with an outsourced backend like Firebase. Next.js also has no state management, that's not related to your question.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your input. I do understand the difference between a library (React) and a framework (Next, Gatsby etc). The question comes down to using a framework to ease and standardise development. If there are no significant added advantages, would it be worth to add an extra layer when things can be easily achieved just the core library. As far as using Firebase etc, that can be done with just pure React as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is no harm for you to hop on NextJS directly, it provides you with many optimisations, routing, api route, etc which React doesn't provide.

Even if you don't need those features from NextJS, you can just leave it alone, it will not cause you any issue.

Unless build size is one of your concern maybe you should always use the simplest library/framework, and only add in more packages when you need them.

Comment: Thanks @khewdev. Build size is not an issue so as SEO. It's more for internal users. we might venture in to NextJS and see how it goes. Thanks.